# SSL Creation Algorithm

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am a advanced programmer in many languages including C, C++, C#, python, JavaScript, perl, HTML, PHP, etc. However, I have been trying to create my own algorithm for website SSL and encryption creation. Is there anyway I could create SSL certificates through my own custom algorithm?

Comment: No. Or, to put it another way, no.

Comment: If you have to ask how to do it, you shouldn't be doing it.  At least not for securing anything "real".  Why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: What use would they be? The software on both ends would have to understand them, meaning you could only talk to yourself. Writing a cryptosystem that is secure takes years of mathematical training and expertise beyond what most programmers have.

Answer (score 4):

Don't Re-Invent the wheel just so because you think you can! You can create a self signed SSL certificate using already available tools for development / learning purposes and need to buy a certificate from valid issuing authority. Then only it can be trusted by other people (Those who are outside your network / control).

Comment: May be I should have made it more clear. What I meant by other people is people in the outside world. If its inside a network you have your own Issuing authority, but still its not advisable to create your own algorithm for certificate creation.

Answer (score 1):

> I have been trying to create my own algorithm for website SSL

You can't. SSL is already defined, and so are X.509 certificates. Your question embodies a contradiction in terms.